# Is there any way to enforce checking dependency version before npm build/yarn run build?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

As Title.

I am working with a team developing on a js application. However, sometimes we will build and deploy the application without aware of some of dependencies is updated. This causes some defects.

Is there any way we can resolve it? Let say any way to enforce checking dependency version before npm build/yarn run build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dependency locking, via a [`yarn.lock`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock/) or a [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-locks.html) file. Checking in the lockfile will ensure that every developer is using the same versions of your dependencies.

Then, before building you can reinstall dependencies with `yarn install` or `npm install` or just validate that local installation matches with `yarn install --check-files` or `npm ci`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the caret sign (^) before versions of packages from your package.json.

This will ensure that the exact version is installed every time you run `npm i` on the server.

Using `package-lock.json` as suggested in the other answer also helps achieve the same.